# Android Gesture Directions

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, gesture, android-2.1-eclair

I'm working on an app that will (hopefully) be taking advantage of Android's gestures (as described here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html)  Before I dive in though, I'm trying to find out if gestures can take the direction they were drawn into account.  Unfortunately I haven't found this information in the documentation.

For example, if the user draws a vertical line on my app, I would like the gesture to register differently depending on if they went from the top of the screen to the bottom compared to if they went from the bottom to the top.  Can I take the drawn direction into account with gestures?  Or is a vertical line a vertical line, regardless of how it was drawn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for you GestureLibrary:

```
    mLibrary.setOrientationStyle(GestureStore.ORIENTATION_INVARIANT[or SENSITIVE]);
    mLibrary.setSequenceType(GestureStore.SEQUENCE_SENSITIVE[or SENSITIVE]);
```

Haven't seen much difference when using both, gestures work quite badly on my phone ...

Comment: You do not really answer the question.